# How does volatile integer fix this thread synchronization issue?

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to solve bounder buffer problem by using spin lock. The condition variable "lock" needs to be defined as volatile when program is compiled with -O option because without it reader will spin in "while(lock == 0) forever. However, I found that even "count" also needs to be defined as volatile. Please see the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>

int count = 0;
volatile int lock = 0;

#define NUM_COUNT       5

static void *
writer(void *arg) {
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0; i < NUM_COUNT; i++) {
        while(lock == 1) {
        }

        printf("Writer count %d ", ++count);
        lock = 1;
    }

    return NULL;
}

static void *
reader(void *arg) {
    static int k = 0;

    while(count < NUM_COUNT) {
        while(lock == 0) {
        }

        printf("reader count %d \n", count);
        if (k > 0 && count!=++k) {
           assert(0);
           printf("reader count %d %d\n", count, k);
        }
        k = count;
        lock = 0;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int
main(void)
{
    pthread_t writer_pthread_id;
    pthread_t reader_pthread_id1;
    void *res;

    pthread_create(&reader_pthread_id1, NULL, reader, NULL);
    pthread_create(&writer_pthread_id, NULL, writer, NULL);


    pthread_join(writer_pthread_id, &res);
    printf("Joined with thread id %lu; return value was %p\n",
           writer_pthread_id, (char *)res);

    pthread_join(reader_pthread_id1, &res);
    printf("Joined with thread id %lu; return value was %p\n",
           reader_pthread_id1, (char *)res);


    printf("count = %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

As per the output, reader seems not be reading the current value.

```
bash-3.2$ gcc -g -Wall -pthread -O    thread_synchro2_bounded_buffer_spin_lock.c bash-3.2$ ./a.out 
Writer count 1 reader count 0 
Writer count 2 reader count 1 
Writer count 3 reader count 2 
Writer count 4 reader count 3 
Writer count 5 reader count 4 
Joined with thread id 47779619322176; return value was (nil)    
Joined with thread id 47779608832320; return value was (nil) 
count =    5
```

However, if I change "count" to "volatile int count" then problem gets fixed.

```
bash-3.2$ gcc -g -Wall -pthread -O thread_synchro2_bounded_buffer_spin_lock.c
bash-3.2$ ./a.out
Writer count 1 reader count 1
Writer count 2 reader count 2
Writer count 3 reader count 3
Writer count 4 reader count 4
Writer count 5 reader count 5
Joined with thread id 47040774805824; return value was (nil)
Joined with thread id 47040764315968; return value was (nil)
count = 5
```

Usually, variable inside the critical section does not need to be volatile as it will not be changed asynchronously. Could someone please help me to understand what compiler optimization is causing this problem?

Comment: The `volatile` keyword have nothing to do with thread synchronization. What is does is basically to inhibit optimizations for expressions where the variable is used. If you need synchronization between threads use primitives like semaphores or mutexes (a special case of a semaphore).

Comment: the `volatile` key word instructs the thread to avoid the cache for that variable. If it is being changed in `Writer`, it forces `Reader` to go to main memory instead of checking the cache first, where an outdated copy exists. However, from what I've read in your code, the `Reader` would be reading 0 every time, but instead it is returning nil

Comment: @Some programmer dude. That is right. However, isn't a condition variable needs to be volatile? I am referring to "volatile, Critical sections and Race conditions" section from the following link http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766.

Comment: Variables used in concurrent read/write or write/write scenarios have to be protected. This typically this is done by using a mutex. Declaring them `volatile` does *not* protect them. In the code you show this applies to `lock` *and* `count`.

Comment: "How does volatile integer fix this thread synchronization issue?" - without reading the code: it does not! Use atomics for simple concurrent data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: For simple types atomics can be sufficient; no need for the big bertha.

Comment: `volatile` never *fixes* a thread synchronization issue, it *hides* it, only to creep up later and bite you. As for why it is "more broken" without volatile: Why should the compiler assume anything not in the current flow of the program could ever change `count`? Remember, C doesn't have any notion of parallelism (well, unless you use atomics and threads provided by C11).

Comment: @FelixPalmen - one of the intentions of volatile is to work with hardware memory mapped I/O, where the hardware can change the value of a memory location outside the current flow. In addition, read / writes to volatile variables can't be done out of order (else hardware based handshakes would not work). If all the variables used to communicate between threads are declared volatile, they will be thread safe (but consume cpu time with spin locks). For read/writes to a mix of volatile and non-volatile variables, the non-volatile read/writes may be re-ordered, so those would not be thread safe.

Comment: Microsoft compilers default to using memory fence operations (release / acquire) on volatiles on non ARM processors, a non-standard implementation, mostly due to legacy usage of volatile before reordering of read/writes occurred due to compiler or processor based optimization.. See [MSDN - volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx).

Comment: @rcgldr I know about volatile and its uses and you're very wrong here: "*If all the variables used to communicate between threads are declared volatile, they will be thread safe*". No, they won't, because `volatile` doesn't set any memory barriers. Values could come from hardware caches or *late* due to pipelining; trying to implement *critical sections* with `volatile` variables will always end up having 2 threads inside the section at the same time. *In short*: `volatile` in threaded code is almost always a bug, at best just unnecessary.

Comment: @FelixPalmen - I had a second comment that didn't get posted that explained that the read or write of a volatile variable had to be inherently atomic in order to be thread safe. [Cache coherency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) will handle any cache issues between cores or processors. If the read/write operations are not inherently atomic, then those variables would not be thread safe, even if declared volatile, and would require some type of atomic interface to work, such as C++ std::atomic.

Comment: @rcgldr well, exactly, and even `sig_atomic_t` doesn't protect from issues with multiple cores. Microsoft's implementation isn't a reference and relying on that just makes the program non-portable. So I rest my case: don't *ever*  use `volatile` for thread synchronization. Use C11 atomics, mutexes (C11, OS specific or `pthread`), etc, all these things that are *meant* for thread synchronization, and leave `volatile` for signals and MMIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable reason for the discrepancy between the `volatile int count` and regular `int count` is compiler optimization in the reader thread.

Since it needs to evaluate `while (count < NUM_COUNT)` in the reader thread, it already has `count` in a register, and later doesn't bother to read it *from memory* again to do `printf("reader count %d \n", count);`. When `count` is volatile, it has to read it again. Between these statements, the writer thread updates `count`.

But multi-threading is tricky and error-prone. Best to use carefully designed and tested idiomatic methods (like atomics library), or to otherwise avoid it altogether and use parallelism in some other part of the calculation.

--- UPDATED ---

Here is a diff of the assembly generated for the two versions of reader thread. It confirms the hypothesis above. For those who parse this, the relevant change are the two lines added above `.LVL10` and the rest of the changes are mainly reloads of count:

```
--- reader.s.nonvolatile    2017-06-16 20:58:26.680644709 +0300
+++ reader.s.volatile   2017-06-16 20:58:29.143644664 +0300
@@ -6,8 +6,8 @@
    .cfi_startproc
 .LVL8:
    .loc 1 29 0
-   movl    count(%rip), %edx
-   cmpl    $4, %edx
+   movl    count(%rip), %eax
+   cmpl    $4, %eax
    jg  .L14
    .loc 1 26 0
    subq    $8, %rsp
@@ -18,6 +18,8 @@
    movl    lock(%rip), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .L10
+   .loc 1 33 0
+   movl    count(%rip), %edx        <--- Reads count again!
 .LVL10:
 .LBB14:
 .LBB15:
@@ -36,7 +38,8 @@
    .loc 1 34 0 is_stmt 0 discriminator 1
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, k.3008(%rip)
-   cmpl    count(%rip), %eax
+   movl    count(%rip), %edx
+   cmpl    %edx, %eax
    je  .L11
    .loc 1 35 0 is_stmt 1
    movl    $__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.3012, %ecx
@@ -52,7 +55,7 @@
    .loc 1 39 0
    movl    $0, lock(%rip)
    .loc 1 29 0
-   movl    %eax, %edx
+   movl    count(%rip), %eax
    cmpl    $4, %eax
    jle .L10
    .loc 1 43 0
```

Comment: With both count and lock declared as volatile, their usage will be thread safe (read / write ordering preserved). Without the volatile on count, even if count was not optimized to be in a register, the compiler and/or processor could reorder the read/write operations with count with respect to read/write operations with lock, getting count out of sync.

Comment: @rcgldr You are right. The compiler basically moved the read of `count` from the `printf` up through the `while` and merged it with the read in the `for`. And it is allowed to do this.